# Is there any other solution for this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation $\sqrt{f(x)}=f'(x)\sqrt{x}$.
Is there any other solution for this differential equation other than $f(x)=x$?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite this as
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{2\sqrt{f(x)}} = \frac 1{2\sqrt{x}}
$$
Integrating both sides with respect to $x$ gives you
$$
\sqrt{f(x)} = \sqrt{x} + C
$$
You should be able to take it from there.

So, for example, $f(x) = x + 2\sqrt{x} + 1$ (for $x\geq 0$) is another solution.

Answer (score 0):

By substition $y^2=z$ the  equation turns to linear differential equation of first order  which has only  one general solution. Of cource it has many partial solutions.